# Illustrator align anchor points to edges in Illustrator on same line

Tags: adobe-illustrator, anchor-point

How can I align anchor points that are on the same line to be the same distance from their respective corners?

So if I had a horizontal line that was 20pt long and I had and anchor point 2pts in from the left, then I had another anchor point that was 5pts in from the right hand side. How could I align the right hand side anchor point so that it was exactly 2pts from the right - the same distance that the anchor point on the left is from the left hand side?

I know this could be done by knowing the measurements, but if I didn't know the measurements is there any way to automatically align these?

I've aligned anchor points on separate lines before to match up but can't figure out how to do this on the same path.
[image]

Comment: maybe I didn't have my coffee yet, but can you [edit your answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/91876/edit) to add an image with an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: You can draw a circle and copy it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this.
Here's one:
select anchor 1 using direct selection tool (white arrow). Make sure you have Smart guides ON. Drag it up to the left anchor point. See the info: it gives you the measurement you need (dX). If you have memory of a goldfish, you can double click on the Direct Selection tool, copy the measurement and cancel.

Ctrl + Z, then select anchor 2, drag it up to far right anchor, double click on the Direct selection tool, paste value, press OK and you're done.

If you must repeat this operation many times, it can easily be scripted.

[image]

**Edit**: Here's another method, which will allow you to achieve what you want with a non-horizontal (or vertical) path:
Select Direct selection tool. Drag anchor 2 to the right-end anchor. Then select anchor 1, and drag it to the left-end anchor. Select anchor 2. Press CTRL + D to repeat last step. Then select anchor 1: Be careful here not to select the left-end anchor! You'll have to press Shift and select by dragging selection zone over the two anchors. Then double click on the Direct selection tool and inverse x and y values. See example below:  [image]

Answer (score 0):

Have the smart quides and snap to point on, no snap to grid!

Drag the anchor point to the right place by using a temporary object that can be the target to snap on. See the cartoon:

[image]

If your original line is not horizontal, replace the flipping by rotating 180 degrees (Object > Transform > Rotate)

Rotate or flip again, if you have added more anchor points than those 2.